# Cross-platform check for port in use

Tags: windows, bash, macos, port, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm looking for a cross-platform way to check if a port is in use so I can print a warning message.

I have accomplished this in macOS:

```sh
if lsof -Pi :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null; then
  echo "Port 8080 is already in use"
fi
```

But this bash script needs to also work on Windows machines. I was looking at something like `netstat -aon | find "8080"`, but I'm unsure how to use that in my script (don't have a Windows machine).

Is there an efficient way to do this? If it helps, the Windows machines have [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/wsl/reference) available to them (but lsof doesn't appear to [work yet](https://github.com/mongodb-js/is-mongodb-running/issues/8)).

Comment: Batch scripts aren't cross-platform. Why do you want this?

Comment: Bash, not Batch :) I also updated my post to note the presence of WSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm certain the other answers would work in certain situations, I just wanted to note I ended up going with the following solution for my own work:

```
if echo PING | nc localhost 8080 >/dev/null; then
  echo "Port 8080 in use"
fi
```

Comment: This is already built into Netcat with a special purpose flag! Just do `nc -z localhost 8080`. No connection will be established either, it will just check if the port is open.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how your network looks like but maybe nmap will be a solution for you. You can scan ports for every pc in your local network using only linux.
If port is open, that mean is in use. This solution will work for any system.

```
apt-get install nmap
```

for example like this:

```
if nmap -p 8080 <ip address> | grep -wq "open"
then
    echo "Port 8080 is already in use"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `netstat` (works on windows, mac, wsl2)

Example `netstat -a | grep :8080` where 8080 is the port you are interested in.

If you are on wsl1 you will need to use the windows netstat as the one included in wsl is broken. Simply set an alias to the windows netstat before using it `alias netstat='/mnt/c/Windows/System32/netstat.exe'`

Comment: thank you! I just gave this a spin and it seems to hang for quite a while - up to 30 seconds. Is this just because there are a lot of ports to check? Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: It might be something to do with name resolution try using the flags `-an` so you only display the numerical form